# Is Nullable DateTime work correct?

Tags: c#, datetime

Please check following code

```
DateTime? tmp = new DateTime();
tmp = null;
return tmp.ToString();
```

It returns `String.Empty`.

Is it correct?

May be it will be better to rise exception in second line of code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx)

> The text representation of the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object if the `HasValue` property is true, or an empty string (`""`) if the `HasValue` property is false.

Note also that `Nullable<T>.Equals` and `Nullable<T>.GetHashCode` do not throw in this case but that `Nullable<T>.GetType` *does* throw. This is because `Object.Equals`, `Object.GetHashCode` and `Object.ToString` are overridden for `Nullable<T>` but that `Object.GetType` is not (because it can not be as it is not marked as `virtual`).

Comment: ok, thanks for you answer. but how you think is it correct way? because if you will use String tmp = null; tmp.ToString() it will rise exception

Comment: Because a nullable type with `HasValue` as false is not a `null` reference. From a conceptual perspective, a nullable type represents a value type with the possibility of the value being "missing." We use `null` to represent when the value is missing, but this is not the same as a `null` reference. Note that `tmp.Value` will throw in the case of `tmp` being an instance of a nullable type with `HasValue` as false. The value is missing so trying to obtain said value should and does throw accordingly.